# Is there any Test App ID for your Application?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, android-manifest

I am building an Android application in Android Studio and I am implementing AdMob.
So, According to the Google AdMob website, you have to add the following in your manifest:-

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Failure to add this would result in an exception.
I am just testing my app and am also using a test AD id for my ads.
My question is that what should be the values for the `android:name` and `android:value`, if you're just testing your app, because I don't have an actual app ID from AdMob.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thanks. I have added those in my ads. But, here I am asking for "APPLICATION ID" and not Ad ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this code

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
```

and use only [this](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml) code,that's work fine

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
        android:value="true"/>
```

Comment: The above value is Interstitial id or not? Shall I need to set any other id which means native ad id will be used here or not? Or it must be the Interstitial id?

Comment: Thank you. This is works! Just follow this instruction. Remove the code from the official tutorial and replace it with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:io';

class AdHelper {

  static String get bannerAdUnitId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111';
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716';
    } else {
      throw  UnsupportedError('Unsupported platform');
    }
  }

  static String get interstitialAdUnitId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";
    } else {
      throw UnsupportedError("Unsupported platform");
    }
  }

  static String get rewardedAdUnitId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313";
    } else {
      throw  UnsupportedError("Unsupported platform");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Give more description not just a code

Answer (score 0):

Add in String file

```
<string name="app_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713</string>
<string name="banner_ad">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
<string name="interstialAd_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample AdMob app ID: `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713` from [documents](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start):

```
<manifest>
  <application>
    <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```